# Elastic Beanstalk with node.js start error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting an error when trying to run a node.js app in elastic beanstalk. I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html) for an express app, but when I inspect the node.js logs, I can see the node process exits with a permissions error. I'm not sure what to do here?

```
> express-test@0.0.1-52 start /var/app/current
> src/server.js

sh: src/server.js: Permission denied

npm ERR! express-test@0.0.1-52 start: `src/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the express-test@0.0.1-52 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the express-test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     src/server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls express-test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /var/app/current
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you have in your `package.json` file in the `scripts` section?

I'm guessing you forgot to put the beginning part of the command and instead it is trying to execute server.js, which is a js file and isn't executable.

Instead, try:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Comment: Kudos to you sir. Saved me hours of debugging.